# Android AsyncTask Hangs using Parse SDK

Tags: android, android-asynctask, parse-platform

Here is a video of the problem

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsTVruQaxqs&feature=youtu.be

Parse.com is our backend and when the user goes to the search activity, I use an asyncTask to download the data from parse.

If the user hits the right combination of buttons, in this case the back button at the right time, then the next time the user goes to the search activity the async tasks will either enter the doInbackground method and hang, or they will not enter at all and the spinner shows indefinitely. Caching does not fix the problem, neither does Pinning the query. If I hit back at the wrong time and try to reload, eventually ill get this behavior.

```
final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                        "UploadedGear");

                final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query2 = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                        "Experiences");

                query.whereEqualTo("status", "active")
                        .whereEqualTo("searchCities", mCity.trim())
                        .setLimit(2)
                        .setSkip(gearSkip);

                query2.whereEqualTo("status", "active")
                        .whereEqualTo("searchCities", mCity.trim())
                        .setLimit(2)
                        .setSkip(expSkip);

                Log.e("query task ", "executing");

                ((DiscoverActivity) getActivity()).addDownloadTask(downloadAction);
                ((DiscoverActivity) getActivity()).addQuery(query);
                ((DiscoverActivity) getActivity()).addQuery(query2);




                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(final List<ParseObject> objs, ParseException e) {


                        if (e != null)
                            query.cancel();


                        ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground("GEAR_RESULTS", objs, new DeleteCallback() {
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e != null) {
                                    return;
                                }

                                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground("GEAR_RESULTS", objs);
                            }
                        });


                        for (ParseObject country : objs) {

                            Log.e("gear size", new Integer(objs.size()).toString());


                            UploadedGear map = new UploadedGear();
                            map.setPrice((String) country.get("Price"));
                            map.setTitle((String) country.get("title"));
                            map.setCity((String) country.get("City"));
                            map.setActivityType((String) country.get("activity"));
                            map.setDesc((String) country.get("description"));
                            map.setObjectId(country.getObjectId());
                            ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
                            ParseUser pointer = (ParseUser) country.get("Owner");
                            map.setOwnerId(pointer.getObjectId());
                            userQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", pointer.getObjectId());

                            map.setOwnerDisplayName("");
                            map.setOwnerUrl("");
                            ParseFile bum = (ParseFile) country.get("icon");
                            map.setImage(bum.getUrl());
                            results.add(map);
                        }


                        if (getActivity() != null) {
                            //ela.setNotifyOnChange(true);

                            EndlessListAdapter el = (EndlessListAdapter) stv.getAdapter();


                            if (el != null) {

                                for (UserContent item : results) {


                                    synchronized (el) {
                                        ((UserContent) item).getActivityType();
                                        if (!el.contains((UserContent) item) && (((UserContent) item).getActivityType().equals(mActivity) || mActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("all"))) {
                                            el.add(item);
                                            if ((UserContent) item instanceof Experience)
                                                expSkip += 1;
                                            else
                                                gearSkip += 1;
                                            el.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                isLoading = false;


                                ((DiscoverActivity) getActivity()).setInitializing(false);


                                if (mFooter == null) {
                                    mFooter = new ListViewFooter(getActivity());
                                }


                                if (results.isEmpty()) {

                                    //set Empty View
                                    if (noGearAvailable == true) {
                                        hideFooter();
                                        hideBar();
                                    }
                                    loadingComplete = true;
                                    hideFooter();
                                } else {

                                }



                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                //query2.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE);

                query2.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {


                    @Override
                    public void done(final List<ParseObject> exps, ParseException e) {


                        ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground("EXPERIENCES_RESULTS", exps, new DeleteCallback() {
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e != null) {
                                    return;
                                }

                                // Add the latest results for this query to the cache.
                                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground("EXPERIENCES_RESULTS", exps);
                            }
                        });


                        hideBar();

                        Log.e("experience size", new Integer(exps.size()).toString());

                        for (ParseObject experience : exps) {
                            Experience exp = new Experience();


                            exp.setImage((String) experience.get("mainImg"));
                            exp.setActivityType((String) experience.get("activity"));
                            exp.setObjectId(experience.getObjectId());
                            ArrayList<String> stringValues = (ArrayList<String>) experience.get("searchCities");
                            exp.setCity(new String(stringValues.get(0)));
                            exp.setTitle((String) experience.get("title"));
                            exp.setDesc((String) experience.get("about"));
                            exp.setPrice("10");


                            ParseUser pointer = (ParseUser) experience.get("Guide");
                            exp.setOwnerId(pointer.getObjectId());


                            exp.setOwnerUrl("");
                            exp.setOwnerDisplayName("");
                            results.add(exp);
                        }

                        if (getActivity() != null) {
                            //ela.setNotifyOnChange(true);

                            EndlessListAdapter el = (EndlessListAdapter) stv.getAdapter();


                            if (el != null) {

                                for (UserContent item : results) {

                                    synchronized (el) {
                                        ((UserContent) item).getActivityType();
                                        if (!el.contains((UserContent) item) && (((UserContent) item).getActivityType().equals(mActivity) || mActivity.equalsIgnoreCase("all"))) {
                                            el.add(item);
                                            if ((UserContent) item instanceof Experience)
                                                expSkip += 1;
                                            else
                                                gearSkip += 1;
                                            el.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                // flag the loading is finished
                                isLoading = false;


                                ((DiscoverActivity) getActivity()).setInitializing(false);


                                if (mFooter == null) {
                                    mFooter = new ListViewFooter(getActivity());
                                }


                                if (results.isEmpty()) {

                                    //set Empty View
                                    if (noGearAvailable == true) {
                                        hideFooter();
                                        hideBar();
                                    }
                                    loadingComplete = true;
                                    hideFooter();
                                } else {

                                }

                            }
                        }


                    }
                });
```

Comment: I think I might be hitting the same problem. My activity somehow hangs  when I get current user.  Did you find the solution?

Comment: I guess this `Parse` bug with `ParseUser` is too much underground as it hasn't been catched by a `Parse` dev here on SO.

Yes, tag dropping. :)